# Analytically: How does Pascal's triangle cook Sierpinski's triangle?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I picked this up from a Reddit post and a corresponding TED-Ed video about Pascal's triangle.

There was a fact in that video that surprised me. There were more but I had figured those out already. Link to the video here. https://youtu.be/XMriWTvPXHI

Eliminating all odd numbers in the Pascal's triangle yields a fractal, more specifically Sierpinski's triangle. I tried to wrap my head around that fact but I couldn't.

Is it possible to tell what patterns form from binomial coefficients that aren't divisible by $2$ and how do these patterns repeat ever so symmetrically. That's my question. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Each dot is a number in the triangle.

Comment: Kummer's Theorem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_theorem may be helpful here.

Comment: Also Lucas's theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem

Comment: So either one of these theorems can tell the placement of odd or even numbers in Pascal's triangle.

Comment: I posted a solution to "this" question last days... have to search for it...

Comment: Is this the "same question"? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3569826/analytically-why-does-sierpinskis-triangle-appear-in-pascals-triangle/3575576#3575576 I.e. is  the present question a duplicate of that one?! If not, please try to point the difference...

Comment: If one of the answers proves the formation of a Sierpinski's triangle yes, this is a duplicate.

Comment: @Plato There is only one answer in *loc. cit.*, it is written to answer exactly the "(analytic) proof" aspect of that question. My answer there does not give the proof, but as much details on the structure to be able to make them formally work. (That question has 3 upvotes, my answer has only one vote, so i did something wrong, although i spent a long time in elaborating and writing down arguments in a short path...)

Comment: @ dan_fulea It is a good answer though. Maybe I can work with rows of $2^n$ and see what I come up with.

Comment: Rather off topic, but please insert my nick name with an at-sign, else i cannot ever see the comments written (also) for me, in case i no longer have the page open...